# Grails/GORM: No signature of method is is applicable for argument types

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to put together a basic blog application using Grails 2.4.4. My domain model is as follows:

```
class Commentable {
  String title
  static hasMany = [comments:Comment]   
}

class Comment extends Commentable {
  static belongsTo = [target:Commentable]
}

class Post extends Commentable {
  static hasMany = [tags:Tag]
}

class Tag {
  String label
  static hasMany = [posts:Post]
  static belongsTo = Post
}
```

In the init method of BootStrap.groovy, I'm trying to create a Post and a Tag as follows

```
def post = new Post();
post.setTitle("Post1");
post.save();

def tag = new Tag();
tag.setLabel("Tag1");
tag.save();

tag.addToPost(post);
tag.save();
```

which produces the error message below:

```
Message: No signature of method: io.dimitris.blog.Tag.addToPost() is 
applicable for argument types: (io.dimitris.blog.Post) values: 
[io.dimitris.blog.Commentable : 1]
Possible solutions: addToPosts(java.lang.Object)
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong would be really appreciated.

Comment: `Possible solutions: addToPosts(java.lang.Object)` . `addToPosts()` instead of `addToPost()`

Comment: Unrelated to the question - your code can be way more concise using the map constructor instead of Java-style individual setter calls, and optionally taking advantage of the option to omit the constructor in `addToXXX`: `def tag = new Tag(label: "Tag1").addToPosts(title: "Post1")` followed by `tag.save()`. The other `save()` calls aren't needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are calling `tag.addToPost(post)` but you need `tag.addToPosts(post)`.  The `hasMany` property is `static hasMany = [posts:Post]`.  The key in that map dictates the method name.  If you change that to `static hasMany = [post:Post]` then the method would be `addToPost(post)`, but the name would make less sense.

Comment: That did the trick - thanks! I seem to have been partly mislead by auto-completion. In version 3.6.3.SR1 of GGTS, I'm still getting an auto-completion suggestion for addToPost(...) but not for addToPosts(...). I understand why addToPosts doesn't appear, however, it's not clear to me where addToPost is coming from - but I guess that's a completely different question. Thanks again!